# Оформление перечня: точка или точка с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, перечисление, точка-с-запятой

Был издан целый ряд учебных пособий. Среди них можно отметить:

- "Название 1";
- "Название 2";
- "Название 3" и др.

Можно ли разделить строки этого перечня (без нумерации) точками с запятой или должны быть точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если перечень представляет собой продолжение фразы (после двоеточия), то тчк/зпт должны отбивать его позиции.

Маркировать список в научном издании следует с помощью тире, а библиографический Список литературы (как раздел исследовательской работы) должен нумероваться арабскими цифрами с абзацным отступом и начинаться с фамилии автора.